# Running hardened Ubuntu 22.04 desktop in an air gapped environment

Tags: linux, apt, ubuntu-22.04, hardening

I am trying to run Ubuntu 22.04 in an a semi Air Gapped environment.

The OS has been hardened using CSI hardening. There is no direct connection to the internet, but there is a Nexus Repo server proxying apt repositories.

Up till now we have been using 20.04 and everything worked fine, but when we try to patch 22.04 we get the error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 : Depends: linux-image-6.5.0-17-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

if I run `apt --fix-broken install` I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-6.5.0-17-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-hwe-6.5-source-6.5.0 linux-hwe-6.5-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-6.5.0-17-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/14.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 14.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 241842 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-6.5.0-17-generic_6.5.0-17.17~22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-6.5.0-17-generic (6.5.0-17.17~22.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-6.5.0-17-generic_6.5.0-17.17~22.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-17-generic.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-6.5.0-17-generic_6.5.0-17.17~22.04.1_amd64.deb
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My /etc/fstab mounts for / and /boot are as follows

/ - xfs defaults 0 1

/boot ext4 defaults 0 1

The output of `mount` for / and /boot are as follows

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
/dev/sda2 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

Grep of /var/log shows the following

```
/var/log/apt/term.log: unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-17-generic.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
/var/log/apt/term.log: unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-17-generic.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
/var/log/apt/term.log: unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-17-generic.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
grep: /var/log/journal/ffe96984df964d1497fbb9324cd333ee/system@00060fdadd825faf-bbdbb03cab0dd0cc.journal~: binary file matches
grep: /var/log/journal/ffe96984df964d1497fbb9324cd333ee/system.journal: binary file matches
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-26 11:46:44,407 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-26 11:47:37,908 - subp.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['grub-probe', '-t', 'disk', '/boot'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-26 11:47:38,516 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-26 13:26:00,587 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-26 13:26:25,002 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-26 14:37:34,484 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-26 14:38:05,565 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-26 14:46:54,308 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-26 14:47:19,119 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-26 15:06:57,497 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-26 15:07:22,845 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-26 15:22:34,506 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-26 15:23:01,216 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-26 15:42:22,328 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-26 15:42:47,693 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 08:46:24,339 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 08:46:49,825 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 08:51:49,049 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 08:52:14,076 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 13:16:16,484 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 13:16:41,634 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 13:18:48,836 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 13:19:13,965 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 13:22:26,210 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 13:22:51,316 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 13:24:59,325 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 13:25:23,657 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 13:36:00,249 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 13:36:24,889 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 14:46:43,354 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-01-29 14:47:08,405 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-02-07 08:17:09,464 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
/var/log/cloud-init.log:2024-02-07 08:17:34,849 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished - wb: [644] 69 bytes
/var/log/syslog:Feb  7 08:17:24 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounting /boot...
/var/log/syslog:Feb  7 08:17:24 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounted /boot.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 08:46:39 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounting /boot...
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 08:46:39 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounted /boot.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 08:52:03 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounting /boot...
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 08:52:03 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounted /boot.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 13:16:30 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounting /boot...
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 13:16:30 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounted /boot.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 13:19:03 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounting /boot...
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 13:19:03 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounted /boot.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 13:22:40 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounting /boot...
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 13:22:40 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounted /boot.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 13:25:13 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounting /boot...
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 13:25:13 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounted /boot.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 13:36:14 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounting /boot...
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 13:36:14 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounted /boot.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 14:46:57 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounting /boot...
/var/log/syslog.1:Jan 29 14:46:57 xxxxxxxxxx systemd[1]: Mounted /boot.
```

Comment: (I appreciate it's probably a PITA in an air-gapped environment) but please do try to use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text when posting console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions. And that allows people willing to answer your question to also copy-paste your commands/settings/error messages into their answer.

Comment: The "`Unable to open /boot/vmlinuz... operation not permitted`" suggests either  a permission issue or  possibly a read-only mounted `/boot` or `/root` file-system

Comment: @vidarlo It is DevOps - a developer trying to do Ops tasks.

Comment: https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/using-guacamole.html#copying-pasting-text

Comment: @HBruijn I have updated my question to show the mount options in /etc/fstab. root and boot do not seem to be mounted read only.

Comment: Show `mount` output, not `fstab` content. The FS could have been remounted automatically due to errors.

Comment: @AlexD Question updated, both / and /boot are mounted RW

Comment: Can you `touch /boot/test-file` ?

Comment: @AlexD yes, that works fine

Comment: Does `/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-17-generic.dpkg-new` exist? Can you do `touch /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-17-generic.dpkg-new` if it doesn't? If it exists check `lsattr` or grep logs for any `apparmor="DENIED"` with paths matching `/boot`.

Comment: @AlexD I am wondering if the problem is because I went with the HWE at install?

Comment: @AlexD No it doesn't exist but all my files in /boot are version 5.4.0-169 and 5.4.0-171 and no mention in /var/log/syslog about /boot

Comment: It doesn't matter which versions of the files. Your system fails to install a `.deb` due to permissions.

Comment: @AlexD no mention on /var/log/syslog about /boot

Comment: The logs could be in dmesg, kern.log or audit/audit.log.

Comment: @AlexD here is the output 

```
grep -R /var/log "/boot"

grep: /boot/vmlinuz.old: Operation not permitted

grep: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-15-generic: Operation not permitted

grep: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic: Operation not permitted

grep: /boot/vmlinuz: Operation not permitted

```

Comment: You got parameters for `grep` in the wrong order. Also, the output is unreadable in the comments, add it to the question.

Comment: @AlexD Question updated with the log entries.

Comment: Were you able to `touch /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-17-generic.dpkg-new`? Or even `echo "test" > /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-17-generic.dpkg-new` to check for write permissions.

Comment: @AlexD Yes, that works fine the fie gets created just fine.

Comment: Title may be more accurate as "Upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04/kernel 6.5 desktop in an air gapped environment fails"

Comment: It's not an upgrade it's a fresh install. My comment before about the version numbers was incorrect. I have 10 terminals open trying to manage different issues and tickets and was looking at the wrong VM.

Comment: When you have time, please focus on a single task and terminal window and re-run all the tests I asked you to do, and update the question with the results.

Comment: what you have is correct, the output of grep on logs is correct, I can create /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-17-generic.dpkg-new and /boot is RW

Comment: run `dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-6.5.0-17-generic_6.5.0-17.17~22.04.1_amd64.deb`.

Comment: I would download a fresh cis Ubuntu image or install a fresh Ubuntu and apply the CIS hardening and restore the data. From my experience I can tell that CIS hardening changes so many things. Once you think you have successfully upgraded there might be upgrades blocked by the CIS hardening which you didn't knew about

Comment: Looks to me like possibly missing packages if you chose the non-standard install (hwe). It could also be that you've run out of disk space on `/dev/sda2` and something has died mid-install.